# Don't work the chest.getInventory.addItem() of JavaPlugin

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

i tried to create a plugin that can share one chest with all player on server in MC.
But when i create this, don't put any item in the chest.

```
if (player.isSneaking() && isEmptyInventory(chest.getInventory()) && !Objects.equals(chest.getCustomName(), "ShareChest"))
            {
                chest.setCustomName("ShareChest");
                
                Inventory inv = getInv();

                if (inv != null)
                    chest.getInventory().setStorageContents(inv.getStorageContents());
                    player.sendMessage(inv.toString());

                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[LorenzoPluginMC] ShareChest impostata");


                chest.update();

            }
```

For take object i create the getInv() function, that take all item in chest and put them in config.yml. So i can take all and put them in when i want.

This is the getInv function:

```
private Inventory getInv ()
    {
        Inventory new_inv = plugin.getServer().createInventory(null, 27, "ShareChest");

        FileConfiguration config = plugin.getConfig();

        // Controlla se la sezione "settings.shareChest.inv" esiste nella configurazione
        if (config.isConfigurationSection("settings.shareChest.inv")) {
            // Ottieni la sezione "settings.shareChest.inv"
            ConfigurationSection invSection = config.getConfigurationSection("settings.shareChest.inv");

            // Leggi i valori dalla sezione "settings.shareChest.inv"
            if (invSection != null) {

                Map<String, Object> valuesMap = invSection.getValues(false); // false indica che non vogliamo i valori da sottosezioni
                for (String key : valuesMap.keySet()) {
                    // Usa i valori come necessario, puoi effettuare il cast a tipi specifici se necessario
                    Object value = valuesMap.get(key);
                    new_inv.addItem(new ItemStack(Objects.requireNonNull(Material.matchMaterial(key)), (int) value));
                }
            }
        }

        return new_inv;
    }
```

I tried many solutions but nothing work.

chest.getInventory().setStorageContents(inv.getStorageContents());
Thi in particular dont work. I tried also with setContents(), but nothing.